# How to use markdown in discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I tried to do it like this:

```
await message.channel.send("**" + current_text + "**")
```

But it doesn't work. It will show the result like this:

**
Hey
**

Comment: It works as expected for me.  What values are you trying for `current_text`?

Comment: I used .text method from BeautifulSoup... And I guess it doesn't work because it added a newline automatically... But like you said, it works... but only on hardcoded/single line text.

Answer (score -1):

For this, I highly recommend using [F-Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498). F-Strings allow you to directly call an variable from a string. This should be easier for you to implement markdown since you can do `f"**{current_text}**"` and `{current_text}` will be replaced with the according variable.